# How can I tell what version of Windows came on my laptop

Tags: windows-8

My laptop is HP and its serial is CND5195Z2X and product number is M9V08PA#CJ,
I want to check with which version I had when I bought the laptop?
Is there any way to do so?
Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: If it came with Windows, it *must* have a Windows logo sticker somewhere. This sticker is sometimes in the battery compartment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-15-ac000-notebook-pc-series/7771404/model/8326126/manuals?sku=M9V08PA) HP support page, it could have shipped with Windows 7 or Windows 8.1.  Do you see a sticker on the computer?  If it was Windows 7, it should have a product key attached to the machine.  If it was Windows 8.1, it should only have sticker that is a Windows logo.